# Check if all string values are integers in a DataTable string column

Tags: datatable, ado.net, validation

I have a DataTable with a column called 'UID' of type string.

**What would be best way to verify that each value is an integer in this column?**

One approach is to loop through each row as in code below (dt variable is a populated DataTable object) and then check the value for UID column using integer.Parse in a try catch block, but may be there is an easier LINQ-based approach.

```
 if( dt!=null)
 {          
            try
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        int.Parse(row["UID"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, you can use `Enumerable.All` to shorten the code:

```
int i;
bool allInts = table.AsEnumerable()
    .All(r => int.TryParse(r.Field<string>("UID"), out i));
```

Comment: How will this throw an exception or let me know that a value is  NOT an integer? Its important for me to know that an invalid value is there, which is not an integer.

Comment: @Sunil: sorry, i have edited my answer to add the type `Enumerable.All` returns. It is a `bool` which indicates whether ot not all fields could be parsed to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var table = YourTable;
int invalidDataCount = table.AsEnumerable().Where(d => d.Field<string>("UID").Contains('-')).Count();
if (invalidDataCount > 0) {
     throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: Why are you counting the rows where the field `UID` contains a hyphen?

Comment: I think he just want's to check if there are non integers?

Comment: Yes, but there are other strings that can't be parsed to `int` which don't contain a hyphen, `"ABC"` for instance.

Comment: From the looks of it, the data are all UID I guess.